# Why prototype function cannot run in javascript twice or more inside it?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a type writer effect in OO Javascript. I tried the same code in Procedural and it works. But, for some reason, it didn't work in OO. Please help me.

Procedural:

```js
var string = 'Hello World! Do you like this effect?';
var animField = document.getElementById('demo');
var counter = 1;
var speed = 75;

function typeWriter(){
 if(counter <= string.length){
  animField.innerHTML = string.substr(0, counter);
  counter++;
  setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
 }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
 <p id = "demo"></p>
```

Object Oriented Javascript Code:

```js
var Typewriters = function(string, speed, printEffect){
 this.string = string;
 this.counter = 1;
 this.speed = speed;
 this.printEffect = printEffect;
};

Typewriters.prototype.typeWriter = function() {
 if(this.counter <= this.string.length){
  this.printEffect.innerHTML = this.string.substr(0, this.counter);
  this.counter++;
  setTimeout(this.typeWriter, this.speed); // Problem is here
 }
};

var settings = new Typewriters('Hello World! Do you like this effect?', 75, document.getElementById('demo'));
settings.typeWriter();
```

```html
<p id = "demo"></p>
```

Please help me. It would be awesome if you explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost the context of the `this` variable. Use `.bind()`.

```js
var Typewriters = function(string, speed, printEffect){
 this.string = string;
 this.counter = 1;
 this.speed = speed;
 this.printEffect = printEffect;
};

Typewriters.prototype.typeWriter = function() {
 if(this.counter <= this.string.length){
  this.printEffect.innerHTML = this.string.substr(0, this.counter);
  this.counter++;
  setTimeout(this.typeWriter.bind(this), this.speed); // Problem is here
 }
};

var settings = new Typewriters('Hello World! Do you like this effect?', 75, document.getElementById('demo'));
settings.typeWriter();
```

```html
<p id = "demo"></p>
```

Comment: Hahah! Thanks a lot Dave.